# How to sync two Arduino in microsecond

Tags: arduino

I am doing a project with Arduino that requires two Arduino boards to transmit microsecond()(time variable in one arduino board that depends on its running time) from one of two arduino boards to another to make them sync. Does attachInterrupt() work? Or is there some other functions helpful to my project?

Answer (score 0):

For what purpose, or how precise does the syncing have to be? I think I would start by using uart or i2c to transmit timing from one master to the other board(s). Repeating the process in intervals to keep the sync accurate.

Use arduino `micros()` function to get the value from the master and send it to the slave(s) as binary, not text, to save on transmission time.

To get even more precision you could really add an interrupt technique. Connect an output pin of the master via a resistor (1k or something for protection) to an interrupt pin of the slave(s) and set it LOW. Then in a defined interval (for example every 1000 microseconds) let the master put the output pin high for a short moment. The slave arduino(s) can attach an interrupt to fine tune their micro reference to master.